# Splitting data out from cells to then extrapolate points

Tags: google-sheets

I have postcode data (the prefix plus the first letter afterwards) all in one cell. I need to just find the different postcode prefixes that each agency covers. In this case for M2, i can see the answer is DE1, DE21, DE22, DE23, DE24, DE3, DE6, DE65, DE7, DE72, DE73, NG10. But i have over 2000 cells that I need to do, so really need a formula/strategy for it.

I think I need to start by splitting out the data into cells, cleaning it up by removing the extra number after the postcode prefix. Then just remove the duplicated prefixes.

Help would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit] your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split()` and `choosecols()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula(
  unique(
    choosecols( 
      split( 
        transpose(split(M2, ", ", false)), 
        " " 
      ), 
      1 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

See [split()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136) and [choosecols()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13197914).